Show part of image only when rubber-band scrolling past the document end
You know rubber-band scrolling on Safari allows to scroll "past" the document end. Is it possible to put an image in a footer of a page, such that only upper half is normally visible (when scrolled all the way down), but lower part is partially visible when you can peek past the end of the document when rubber-band scrolling?

I asked a very similar question a few years ago. One of the comments helped me come to a solution. I can't remember the original solution, but I've found an alternate solution that I think is probably better than whatever my original solution was:
You can add a fixed image that fills the whole screen (or part of the screen in your specific situation), and then put a wrapper element over all the rest of your content. Then you can use z-index to put your content in front of the image. Here is an example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rubberband Footer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
</body>
</html>

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: url("your-image.png");
}

This will allow the rubber-banding effect to work with an image in the background, instead of the default white background of the html element. It is important to set position: relative for main-content, or else the z-index won't work with the background being a fixed element.
In your specific situation, if you want the image to be partially visible, you can just add some margin to the bottom of main-content, and move the image to wherever you want it to show (for example set bottom: 0; instead of top: 0 as I did earlier).
Here is an example of that in action:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rubberband Footer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
</body>
</html>

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 100px; //The height will determine how much of the the image is shown before any rubber-band scrolling happens
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0; //you can adjust how high the image starts or stops with this value
  background: url("your-image.png");
}

What's cool is you can use this to put different pictures on the top and bottom of the screen of the rubber-band scrolling. For example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rubberband Footer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top-background"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="bottom-background"></div>
</body>
</html>

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 3;
}

.top-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; //you can adjust how high the image starts or stops with this value
  background: url("image1.png");
  z-index: 1;
}

.bottom-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0; 
  background: url("image2.png");
  z-index: 2; //just in case the top image background is super tall and covers the whole height of the page, setting a higher z-index will ensure this is still visible. Ideally you would probably want to use images that are only as tall as you need them to be, to increase loading times.
}


The problem is when you want to set any background image outside of viewpoint  or negative px like margin: -10px it all cut off.  You can only set background-color.

The only solution comes to my mind is, using overscroll-behavior:none  to disable browser default effect and then make similar effect with Javascript

@CyrusRaoufi Yes, that is why I set the background element to a fixed div, and use a wrapped container, instead of setting the background-image to the body element itself. That way I simulate the image being outside the viewport, when it actually isn't.

Even with fix div it will still cut off and doesn't work, it been more than hours that I've trying all of these solutions

@CyrusRaoufi I don't know what to tell you. I just tested this solution and it's working for me. I would encourage you to try out my code.

oh cool you right, it works, I've actually tested with position sticky and absolute. but it looks it works with fixed.  Nice

Yes, it is possible to achieve the effect you're looking for using a combination of CSS and HTML. Here’s how you can do it:
You can place the image in a fixed position at the bottom of the page and then use a combination of overflow: hidden and position: fixed to ensure that only the top part of the image is visible when the document is fully scrolled. When rubber-band scrolling occurs, the lower part of the image will become visible as you "peek" past the end of the document.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        /* This ensures that the page takes up the full height */
        .content {
            background-color: burlywood;
            min-height: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 50px; /* Space for the visible part of the image */
        }

        /* The footer image */
        .footer-image {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 100px; /* Total height of the image */
            overflow: hidden; /* Hide the bottom part initially */
        }

        .footer-image img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            transform: translateY(50px); /* Adjust this value to show the desired part of the image */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Your content here -->
        <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing of a pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?
On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammeled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.</p>
        <div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/04/20/14/sunset-1645103_1280.jpg" alt="Footer Image">
    </div>
</body>
</html>



